# Jquery hover over this class

Tags: jquery, css

I cam up with this code to add whatever the text is as the class name:

```
$(".entry-content p").each(function( index ) {
                    var className = $(this).text();
                    className = className.toLowerCase().replace(/ /g, '-');
                    $(this).addClass(className);
                });
```

Now I am trying to code a hover function that will only work for the class name like so:

```
$('.entry-content p.' + $(this).attr("class")).hover(function(){
```

but when I hover over my paragraph it does not work, however if I put in the class name (lets say the class name is 180-paragraph) instead of $(this).attr("class") like so:

```
$('.entry-content p.180-paragraph).hover(function(){
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: `$(this).attr("class")` ? where are you binding this hover? inside an `.each` ?

Comment: Make a JSFiddle would be ideal, then you should get an answer pretty quickly

Comment: Please do alert() or console.log() on $(this).attr("class") before you call your jQuery code and tell us if the output is what you would expect it to ne.

Comment: AS you are adding class to all p elements why can't you bind the hover event there? Check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/Lw8Ka/

Comment: Also why do you want the p tag text as a class name?

Comment: NOUPHAL.M!!!! that worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Your main problem is here:

```
$('.entry-content p.' + $(this).attr("class")).hover(function(){
```

You can't use `$(this)` because you're not inside of a jQuery function handler, so it is unavailable.

Secondly, `addClass` simply adds classes to the `class` attribute of elements, so you could end up with a class attribute like this:

```
<p class="one two three">...</p>
```

So, your selector would then be this, which is wrong:

```
$('.entry-content p.one two three').hover(...
```

Also, you are missing a `'` here:

```
$('.entry-content p.180-paragraph).hover(...
```

Comment: Well said.  Too bad the fellow didn't mark your answer as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use as following

```
$('.entry-content').on('mouseover', 'p.your_class_name_here', (function(){
```

or for your code here:

```
$('.entry-content').on('mouseover', 'p.'+(this).attr("class"), function(){
```

And be sure that your class attribute contain single class. Because multiple class based selector (i.e. $('.clase_one.class_two')) is different than $('class_one class_two') which contain class attribute in your case. Which means select element with 'class_two' where one of parent have 'class_one' in your case if it contains more than one class in your class attribute.

Look for **[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/GZG8t/1/)** here.